# rmagick does not overwrite EXIF property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I'm trying to reset the Orientation EXIF field in my image using rmagick 2.13.1 and ruby 1.9.3p194, but it doesn't seem to save.

```
img = ::Magick::Image::read(local_source_path).first
img.get_exif_by_entry()
=> [["ColorSpace", "1"],
 ["ExifImageLength", "2448"],
 ["ExifImageWidth", "3264"],
 ["ExifOffset", "38"],
 ["Orientation", "6"]]
```

Orientation can also be acquired thru the properties

```
img.properties
```

outputs

```
{"date:create"=>"2014-01-08T17:26:10-08:00",
 "date:modify"=>"2014-01-08T17:26:05-08:00",
 "exif:ColorSpace"=>"1",
 "exif:ExifImageLength"=>"2448",
 "exif:ExifImageWidth"=>"3264",
 "exif:ExifOffset"=>"38",
 "exif:Orientation"=>"6",
 "jpeg:colorspace"=>"2",
 "jpeg:sampling-factor"=>"2x2,1x1,1x1"}
```

I try to set Orientation property to `nil` & save:

```
img['exif:Orientation'] = nil
```

Now,

```
img.properties
=> {"date:create"=>"2014-01-08T17:26:10-08:00",
 "date:modify"=>"2014-01-08T17:26:05-08:00",
 "exif:ColorSpace"=>"1",
 "exif:ExifImageLength"=>"2448",
 "exif:ExifImageWidth"=>"3264",
 "exif:ExifOffset"=>"38",
 "jpeg:colorspace"=>"2",
 "jpeg:sampling-factor"=>"2x2,1x1,1x1"}
```

which looks correct.

```
img.write(local_dest_path)
```

but when I use `get_exif_by_entry`

```
img.get_exif_by_entry('Orientation')[0][1]
```

I still get 6 & not `nil`.

When I read the written file that was modified `local_dest_path`, I still get "6".

Is there a `set_exif_by_entry` function that I'm missing? Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: i'v tried right now with Rmagick 2.13.2 and it works. Try to update the rmagick to latest.

Comment: Still doesn't work with 2.13.2 :(

Comment: Here's an even simpler experiment: `img['exif:Orientation'] = nil; img['exif:Orientation']`  Do you still get "6" or nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't set to `nil`, but I was able to set it to 1 during the write

```
img.write('local_dest_path') { self.orientation = ::Magick::TopLeftOrientation }
```

The constant `UndefinedOrientation` didn't work either. Other values available are listed in [OrientationType](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/constants.html#OrientationType).